# Django-social-auth and twitter update status

Tags: python, twitter, django-socialauth

I want create application with **django-social-auth**. How can I get users possibility update twitter status? 
I try to use tweepy, but it write me:

```
Invalid / expired Token
```

I use **consumer_key** and **consumer_secret** from my application, and **oauth_token** with **oauth_token_secret** from **usersocialauth** table in database.

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(settings.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY, settings.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(str(oauth_token), str(oauth_token_secret))
api = tweepy.API(auth)
api.update_status(TwiAge)
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: I was stupid, and put comma in wrong place. It convert my string to tuple, and all broked. Now all ok